# Matlab - Feedforward net producing same accuracy with difrent value of epoch

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, feed-forward

I am working with ANN (feedforward net). My training function is `trainlm`. I've also tried other training functions. Dimension of my training dataset is : `InputData : 7x1000` and `TargetData : 4x1000`. I set `max_fail` parameter to a very high value so, network can complete/run for all epochs.

I have a problem with the fact that when I am using training function `trainlm`, with different number of epochs (e.g. 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000) for every such value network gave me the same results.

So, why this happened with this network? Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you give us more details (e.g. what is the value of the accuracy and loss etc.)

Comment: @marcin : accuracy is around 87.9 %

Comment: And what are percentages of each classes in your dataset?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko :  I can't understand your last question.. ! You mean 

`Class1 --> 40% + Class2 --> 40% + Class3 --> 10% + Class4 --> 10% = Input Data (All Class 100%)` Like this.......

Comment: Yes - this is what I'm asking for :)

Comment: @MarcinMożejko : I have 4 class and each class has 25 % of the data and all class are equal in percentage.